# Rails: How to Create a New Associated Model From a Collection of Templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to have a series of workout templates a user can select when making a booking. The booking version of the workout template can be edited without changing the original template.

**Context**

- I have a personal trainer who makes bookings with their clients.
- The personal trainer has many workouts.
- Each booking has an associated workout that can be edited for that booking.

**Question**
How do I create a new workout with each booking and:

- Associate the new workout's id with the booking
- Keep only the template workouts in the collection that is displayed at the new booking form

**Guess**
My current guess on doing this is to have a hidden field with the workout params in the form which is passed to the bookings_controller, the create method then would `@booking.save && @workout.save` however I'm completely stuck on the details to execute.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand what you are trying to do but it looks like you want to use:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Thanks, I think it's close. I'll post here if (hopefully when) I get an answer. Apologies if my explanation wasn't clear

Comment: sure. this railscast might help also:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: Thanks heaps, I've been through the nested form & complex form series in railscast as well as Rails API & haven't been able to solve the issue. I've restated the problem from a new angle here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091929/rails-complex-form-selecting-and-working-with-templates if you can help, please do!