# Rails Complex Form: selecting and working with templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_one :template 
end 

class Template < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :project, foreign_key: "project_id" 
  belongs_to :admin
end 

class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :templates
end
```

Given I'm a user, I want to select a Template when creating a new Project.

I then want to edit the @project & @project.template without changing the Admin's Template.

======ISSUE========

I haven't been able to find a resource that shows how to:

- Gather a collection_select of Template.all
- Pass the selected template's attributes (except :id) to @project.build_template
- Create a new instance of Template (inc associations & attributes) associated with the new Project

Comment: I am still green with Rails, but the way I use collection_select would be the following: In your project controller you would have `@templates = Template.all` and in your project form you would have `<%= label_tag :template %>
 <% unless @templates.blank? %>
  <%= collection_select(:template_id, @templates, :id, :name, :prompt => "select a template" )%>
 <% else %>
  <%= select_tag "template_id","template_id", :prompt => "There are no templates available." %>
 <% end %>`

Comment: Thanks, I've attempted your suggestion in a couple of different ways with no luck. The issue is that the template collection isn't associated to the project ie the project needs to create/build the template.

Comment: Did you define the attr_accessible such as for your project model `attr_accessible :name, :template_id`? I have a similar case and I didn't need to do `@project.template.build` as long as it doesn't have a has_many :through association.

Comment: I did set attr_accessible... do you have your code in a public repo?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it. First, you need to build a new template in the Project new action.

```
template.build
```

Then add the collection_select. Something like this:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:random_virtual_attribute, Templates.all, :id, :name, {:include_blank => true}, {:multiple => false} ) %>
```

Then attach to the change event on the select. When, it changes, make a JSON request to get that particular template. You can use respond_to and respond_with, http://davidwparker.com/2010/03/09/api-in-rails-respond-to-and-respond-with/. In the callback of the JSON request, set all of the fields_for of the template you built.

Comment: Not how I've achieved it (answer that needs refactoring below) but thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I've reached is

(1) Scope the templates that the admin created. Don't show duplicates.

app/models/template.rb

```
scope :unique_title, where(admin: true).order(:title).select("DISTINCT title").select(:id)
```

(2) Collect the scoped templates in the form

project/create.html.haml

```
= simple_form_for @project do |f|
  = simple_fields_for :template do |template_form|
    = template_form.input :id, collection: admin.templates.unique_title
```

(3) Create a new project & then call a method in Project to create a new template based on @template's attributes

app/controllers/projects_controller.rb

```
def create
  @project = Project.new(params[:project[)
  @template = Template.find(params[:template][:id])
  if @project.save
    @project.create_new_template(@template)
  ....normal stuff here....
end
```

(4) Create the new template object in Project

```
  def create_new_template(template)
    self.build_template do |t|
      t.title = template.title
      ...other template attributes here....
      t.save!
    end
  end
```

This works but makes me want to take a shower... the controller is getting way too muddled. I would like to instantiate the new template after_create on the Project however I'm not sure how to access the template params. Will post the solution if I can refactor. If anyone has suggestions/criticisms they're greatly received.